# Import selected rows with query on importrange

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to import select rows from a Google spreadsheet based on the value of a single cell in each row.

As such, I'm using the following:

```js
=query(IMPORTRANGE("KEY","Form Responses 1!A:L"), "select * where J contains 'DENIED' ")
```

Wherein the `KEY` is an actual spreadsheet Key. I tested the `importrange` part, that is without the query, to confirm it works. It does. Furthermore, within the Google Spreadsheet itself I can `query` the sheet and get it to work.

The error I receive is:

> #VALUE Error Unable to parse query string for query parameter 2: NO_COLUMN_J

(There is a column J.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use an importrange as a dataset, you need to refer to the columns by number rather than letter.  The formula also works without 'select *'.  Try:

`=query(IMPORTRANGE("KEY","Form Responses 1!A:L"),"where Col10 contains 'DENIED'")`